# Problem with the TransitionDrawable

Tags: android, animation, transition

I am using **TransitionDrawable** to display ***set of images with the transition between the*** .With the code in my activity:

```
TransitionDrawable simons;
 simons=(TransitionDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
         simons.startTransition(2000);
         frame.setImageDrawable(simons);
```

And with the xml file in the res/drawable folder containing **three images**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/simon" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/simons" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/chipmubnks" android:duration="500" />
</transition>
```

The problem i face is, only the **first two** images **appears with the transition** between them, the ***third image doesn't appear*** .Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Hi friends . I just found that the TransitionDrawable can be applied only to two drawable resources.Thanks for those who put effort to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen it before? [Creating a frame animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174277/creating-a-frame-animation-in-android) or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html