# Creating a frame animation in android

Tags: android, animation, frame, android-animation

Hi im trying to set up a frame animation with a series of images as a background for my splash page in an android application, I would if possible like the code to run on start up. I have been writing the code but get an error that says "frame animation cannot be resolved".

The java code I have implemented in my main activity is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView frameanimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame_animation);
        AnimationDrawable frame_animation = (AnimationDrawable) frameanimation.getBackground();

        frame_animation.setVisible(true, true);
        frame_animation.start();
    }
```

I then have this code implementing an image view within my XML Layout file:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frame_animation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_animation" />
```

and finally I have my animation drawable saved as 'frame_animation.xml' within my drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda8" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda9" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda10" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda11" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda12" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda13" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda14" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda15" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda16" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda17" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Any help is much appreciated, I just cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source of ImageView (`android:src`) and background of ImageView (`android:background`) are different things. You are setting the **source** in XML but trying to get the **background** image in the code (`frameanimation.getBackground()`).

Comment: Thanks I added the android:background attribute to my imageview within my xml file and it eradicated the error, but when I run the code in the emulator it quits unexpectedly as soon as you run it, is there anything else that would stop this from working?

Comment: @user1161118 I don't know what may be the cause of crash. See the log in [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#startingLogcat).

Comment: The first error I get in the log is after 10 garbage collections, I then get the error: 1234272-byte external allocation too large for this process. followed by shutting down VM and Fatal exception: main. Is there any reason why the animation would cause such a large allocation, maybe my image sizes are too large.

Comment: May be it is image sizes. You can easily check it - temporarily remove the frame animation code.

Comment: I removed the animation code and it is definitely this that is causing a memory leak, or the image sizes are too large. The images are all 50k or less and I have 17 of them in the animation, this shouldnt be too large for android should it?

Comment: I don't know solution for this memory problem. Try to post new question.